# Return the previous recurring number in one column before another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to determine the buy and sell points for trend analysis in a dataset. Here is a sample of the data: The first column is buy, second column is sell.

```
1 [0, 0]
2 [1, 0]
3 [0, 0]
4 [0, 0]
5 [1, 0]
6 [0, 0]
7 [0, 0]
8 [0, 1]
9 [0, 0]
10 [1, 0]
```

The 2nd row says buy, so it's unnecessary for the 5th row to say buy as well, as I want to buy at the lowest price. How can I make the 5th row 0,0 since I want the next 1 to be row 8 (sell).

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple loop would do the trick no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data "in-place" you will need VBA. If you want to generate the modified indicators in two new columns, say for example C and D, use the following *CSE formulas* in C2 and D2 (enter each of them and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter), then fill down columns C and D:

```
C2:
=A2*IFERROR(MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*$A$1:$A1)<=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*$B$1:$B1),1)
' Ctrl+Shift+Enter

D2:
=B2*IFERROR(MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*$A$1:$A1)>=MAX(ROW($A$1:$A1)*$B$1:$B1),1)
' Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the VBA solution:

```
Sub analyzecells()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 100
    If Not ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = 0 And _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = 1 Then
            For j = i + 1 To 100
                If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value <> 1 Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j).Value = 0
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value = 0
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```